# How to run code inspection on an entire project in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I have and Android Studio project I haven't opened in months, and when I look at some individual files there's warning and errors that appear (missing permissions, deprecated functions, etc.).

I want to see all these errors/warnings at once instead of having the navigate to each file to see if it contains any.

When I run **Code > Inspect Code** with an inspection scope of **Whole project**, all it returns are warnings about typos and unknown XML attributes:

[image]

However, when I run an inspection with a scope of an individual file, it returns errors that aren't in the whole project scope:

[image]

The **Inspection Profile** is the same same in each case: Project Default.

Am I doing something wrong, and is there a way to see all warnings/errors for the entire project?

Answer (score 0):

> ***Run code inspection on an entire project in Android Studio***

Step 1:

**Got to File>Settings>Plugins**

Step 2:

- Search for Plugin ***SonarLint*** and install it.
  [image]

Step 3:

Right Click on your project directory and analyze it with sonarLint. You will get all the warnings, errors and code improvements.
[image]

Thank you.